# Add new input value with existing input value and shown up

Tags: php, mysql

The requirement is when i enter a new value into input field and press the update button then it should add with existing value and answer will shown into same input field. 
please help me in this scenario. thanks in advance.

```
 <?php
        include("../assets/includes/header.php");
        require_once("../assets/db/connect.php");

        /**************** UPDATE QUERY COUNTER CASH   **************************/ 
        if(isset($_POST['update_btn_counter']))
        {
            mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE aks_counter SET counter_balance='$_POST[balance]' WHERE counter_id='$_POST[counter_hidden]' ");
        }

        $countercash_query = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM aks_counter");
    ?>

    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>AKS</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href="../assets/css/aks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="../assets/css/mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body class="pages" id="customer">

    <div class="container">


            <h2> Counter Cash </h2>
    <?php 
        while ($counter_row = mysqli_fetch_array($countercash_query))
        { 
               echo "<form action=balance1.php method=post id=counter_cash_form>";
               echo "<input type=submit name=update_btn_counter value=Update>";
               echo "<input type=number class=input_field name=balance value='" . $counter_row['counter_balance'] . "'>";

               echo "<input type=hidden name=counter_hidden value='" . $counter_row['counter_id'] . "'>";
               echo "</form>";
        }
    ?>


        </div>  

    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use + instead of =

counter_balance +'$_POST[balance]'